# Parse Json result and isolate specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my returned JSON:

```
{  
   //...
   "results":[  
      {  
         //more properties...
         "geometry":{  
            "lat":51.2244644,
            "lng":0.7334215
         }
      },
      //more results...
   ],
   //...
}
```

[Complete JSON](https://gist.github.com/hiven/6335bf6ff4c98e217b3c)

I want to get information from a json result returned without having to use a specific companies JS helper file, just using the pure result myself. I'm looking to isolate results lat and lng shown here:

```
 "geometry":{  
    "lat":51.2244644,
    "lng":0.7334215
 }
```

It seems like I can use code similar to this to get my result:

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.count);
```

How can I get the first coordinates returned in the result so I can later store them in an input box? I don't mind using jQuery if it simplifies this.

Comment: make a fiddle and show some code and result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get first coordinates like following.

```
var json = '{"results":[{"geometry":{"lat":51.2244644,"lng":0.7334215}}]}';
var first_coordinate = JSON.parse(json).results[0].geometry;

console.log(first_coordinate);
```

If you want to get all coordinates in an array then try like following.

```
var arr = $(JSON.parse(json).results).map(function () {
    return this.geometry;
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

USE like this after JSON parsing

co-ordiniates from DMS

```
myArray.results[0].annotations.DMS
```

co-ordinitates from gemotery

```
myArray.results[0].geometry
```

You need to loop the `results` to get all co-ordinates